# Why is this left join fetch not retrieving an entry?

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I am attempting to write a `Hibernate` query to retrieve an entity for a given id. This entity has a collection of another entity, but I only want to retrieve non-deleted entities to populate the collection:

Top-level entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="rss_feed_definition")
public class RSSFeedDefinition extends BaseEntity {

    [...]

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="rssFeedDefinitionId")
    private Collection<RSSFeedProperty> rssFeedProperties;

    [...]
```

and the HQL:

```
em.createQuery("from RSSFeedDefinition definition left join fetch definition.rssFeedProperties property where property.deleted = false and definition.id = :id");
```

Why is it not returning the RSSFeedDefinition, even though I am left joining on the property (that has a deleted flag of true)?

Comment: Because your `where` clause filters on the joined table. You need to include that condition into the `left join`.

Comment: Sorry I can't quite see the error, could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Hibernate expert but in pure SQL your problem is this:

```
select * 
from RSSFeedDefinition definition 
left join property on definition.someField = property.otherField 
where property.deleted = false <--- this is the problem because it filters all data
and definition.id = :id
```

It should be like this:

```
select * 
from RSSFeedDefinition definition 
left join property on definition.someField = property.otherField 
                  and property.deleted = false
where definition.id = :id
```

to filter only when the join could be made.

Comment: From what I have gathered so far it seems that JPA does not support filtering on fetches. If I'm not mistaken the only other alternative would be 2 queries. The first to retrieve the top-level entity and the second to retrieve the collection.

Answer (score 0):

JPA doesn't support any conditions in a JOIN FETCH statement. But in your case, you can use the following workaround:

```
TypedQuery<RSSFeedDefinition> q = em.createQuery("SELECT definition FROM RSSFeedDefinition definition LEFT JOIN FETCH definition.rssFeedProperties property WHERE property.deleted = false or property.deleted = IS NULL and definition.id = :id", RSSFeedDefinition.class);
```

If there is no property associated with the definition, its attributes are `null`. So, you need to check if `deleted`is `false` or `null`.